# Getting memory stored in address space

Tags: memory, byte, memory-address, microprocessors

"If a computer handles data in 8-bit sizes and uses a 16-bit address to store and retrieve data in memory, its address space contains 2^16 (65536) bytes or 64k bytes"

My text book has this statement that I'm confused by. Where are they getting 2^16 from? If a computer uses a 16-bit address why isn't that just a 2 byte address space? The textbook hasn't explained how memory is stored in microcomputers and has this statement in the intro chapter. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If an address is 16 bits, it means that you have 16 bits when referring to a *location* in memory. The address space is the range of valid addresses, not the physical size of an address.

These addresses start at address 0 (binary `0000 0000 0000 0000`) and go up to address 2<sup>16</sup>−1 (binary `1111 1111 1111 1111`). That's total of 2<sup>16</sup> addresses that can be referenced. And if each address refers to 8 bits (i.e. a byte), the total amount of memory that you can refer to with those addresses is 2<sup>16</sup> × 8 bits, or 2<sup>16</sup> bytes.

As a smaller example, consider a system with 3-bit addresses, each referring to 4 bits (a nibble).

```
Address | 0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
Memory  | 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
Binary  |
address | 000  001  010  011  100  101  110  111
```

The 3-bit addresses can have 2<sup>3</sup> values, from 0 to 7, and each refers to 4 bits of memory, so this system has a total of 2<sup>3</sup> = 8 nibbles of memory.

In this system, the only valid address are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7, so the address *space* is the set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}.

As an important point, don't forget that the address space is not necessarily the actual amount of memory available—computers use some handy tricks to use addresses spaces much larger than the memory they actual have available (for example, a 64-bit system can theoretically address 2<sup>64</sup> bytes of memory, but you don't even have a fraction of that in your computer).

---

## Analogies for address spaces

Here are two analogies that might help you understand the difference between an address space, an address, and a pointer:

- The web address space is the set of all URLs, basically the set of strings of the form `https://[domain]/[path]`. So `https://example.com/page` is an address, and [this link](https://example.com) is a pointer to that address.
- The United States street address space is (approximately) the set of strings of this form:

  ```
  [First name] [Last name]
  [number] [Street name]
  [Town], [STATE] [zip code]
  ```

  In the same analogy, this is an address:

  ```
  John Doe
  10 Main St.
  Faketown, NY 20164
  ```

  Finally, a pointer is then analagous to the writing on the front of an envelope that the postal service uses to deliver letters.

Comment: Do the address spaces work as pointers to memory location? And how does the processor find the data with a single bit of information? Thanks for your response.

Comment: I've added another sentence and two analogies to my answer that might help you understand what address spaces are. As for how computers use addresses, your textbook may have a section on how that works, and if not, I recommend asking it as a new question—that starts to get into a few other topics, depending on how much you want to know. (And if I answered your original question, please accept my answer by clicking the check mark next to it.)